# Sqoop append with renaming (-Dmapreduce.output.basename) not creating files in HDFS

Tags: sqoop

I'm trying to import some records from source using sqoop. I want to add all the output (from multiple runs) to the same folder & also have custom basename for each run (using -Dmapreduce.output.basename).

Files gets successfully created in the TEMPORARY directory, but for some reason when it is trying to move to the actual HDFS output location, it says "ignored"..

Can someone please advise what is causing it to be ignored. Below is the sqoop command with the output (used verbose).  sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.12.0.

Also note that the target HDFS directory was empty when I tried this.

```
user_1@system1 /home/sriadmin$ sqoop-import -Dmapreduce.output.basename="12345_" --connect "jdbc:sap://xx.xx.xx.xx:30215" --username "EDHQUERY" -password xxxxxxxxxx  --driver "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver" --query "SELECT PLANT FROM SAPBWT.PLANT where \$CONDITIONS" --split-by "PLANT" --target-dir "/tmp/SRITEST/HANA_Extract_Plant/" --as-textfile --fields-terminated-by "|" --num-mappers "2" --append  --verbose
    Map-Reduce Framework
            Map input records=6428
            Map output records=6428
            Input split bytes=212
            Spilled Records=0
            Failed Shuffles=0
            Merged Map outputs=0
            GC time elapsed (ms)=305
            CPU time spent (ms)=4760
            Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=737996800
            Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=10986500096
            Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1584398336
    File Input Format Counters
            Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters
            Bytes Written=31774
18/05/29 11:19:30 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 31.0293 KB in 41.4266 seconds (766.9945 bytes/sec)
18/05/29 11:19:30 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 6428 records.
18/05/29 11:19:30 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@47d384ee
18/05/29 11:19:30 INFO util.AppendUtils: Appending to directory HANA_Extract_Plant
18/05/29 11:19:30 DEBUG util.AppendUtils: Filename: 12345_-m-00000 ignored
18/05/29 11:19:30 DEBUG util.AppendUtils: Filename: 12345_-m-00001 ignored
18/05/29 11:19:30 DEBUG util.AppendUtils: Filename: _SUCCESS ignored
18/05/29 11:19:30 DEBUG util.AppendUtils: Deleting temporary folder     634e75fe8ca94ba79c0b5fbbffdffe18_4056a33f
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an existing bug -

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-3330

Sqoop moves only files with filename starting with 'part*'. .. The work around is to maintain your -Dmapreduce.output.basename="part.*" 
(example : -in my case Dmapreduce.output.basename="part.12345_" )